# Orientation and the change of variables formula for integration

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry

I have a question regarding the change of variable formula and orientation. I have seen the change of variable formula written as

$\int_{V}f\left ( v \right )dv = \int_{U}f\left ( \phi \left ( u \right ) \right )\left | det\left ( Du\right ) \left ( u \right )\right |du$

My concern here is taking the absolute value of the determinant since it seems to me that it is the sign of the determinant/Jacobian that determines whether the orientation has been switched. For example consider the very easy switch of orientation: $x \mapsto y=-x$, with the vary simple integral

$\int_{0}^{1}dx$

Using the change of variable formula above and taking that absolute value of the Jacobian then we have

$\int_{0}^{1}dx=1=\int_{0}^{-1}\left | \frac{dx}{dy} \right |dy=\int_{0}^{-1}\left | -1 \right |dy=\int_{0}^{-1}dy=\left [ y \right ]_{0}^{-1}=-1$

This obviously wrong; and it is the fact that I have taken the absolute value of the determinant that has caused it to be wrong.

So my question is, if we want to worry about a change in orientation, should we really take the absolute value of the determinant?

Comment: There is a mistake in what you wrote: when you make the change of variable the domain you write in the new integral is already oriented in the right way. This means that $\int_{0}^{1} dx = \int_{-1}^{0} dy $.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is just in the definition.
When you consider 1-dimensional integrals you consider them oriented, but when you consider n-dimensional integrals you don't consider them oriented because such a notion don't make sense for all the misurable subsets of $\mathbb{R^n}$